# Is it a magnetic or an electric field that causes induction in the antenna?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, conductors, electromagnetic-induction, antennas, radio-frequency

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)) says that:

> The electric field (E, green arrows) of the incoming wave pushes the
>   electrons in the rods back and forth, charging the ends alternately
>   positive (+) and negative (−).
>   [image]

but isn't it a magnetic field that makes a charge oscillate?

I am adding a picture, canyou please explain how it should work? the wave propagates on the x axis, how do we know that there is an electric field/ potential on the wave in the z axis?
[image]

Comment: The EM wave propagates like this : a change in B field creates a change in E field, and then a change in E field creates a change in B field, and so on. 
The total energy (electric + magnetic) is always the same; only that when E field energy decreases the B field energy increases.
In the case when the antenna is a coil like those used in long/medium wavelengths, the magnetic component of the EM wave is what induces a current in the coil. 
But in your case the E field is the main source of charge oscillation.

Comment: These are the kind of antennas in which the magnetic field is the main contributor : https://www.google.com/search?q=long+wave+radio+coil&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X

Comment: The force acting on the electrons on the long bars is $\vec{F} = q \vec{E}$. They (electrons) will gather at the ends of the wire, creating in this way a potential across the wire $|dV| > 0$ (between the 2 sides of the antenna) like in a capacitor. The current that you see in the perpendicular wires is due to the flow of electrons from one side to the other side like in the discharge of the capacitor.

Comment: The potential difference will make them move. The more power the wave  will have the more electrons will be gathered. At the peek of the cycle you will have the charge $q$ stored on one side  and $-q$ on the other side. This will create a potential $dV = dq/C$ (across the "circuit") which depends on antenna's capacitance $C$.

Comment: Here are some schematics which involve this kind of process  (R-C radio antena - resistor-capacitor) : https://www.google.com/search?q=RC+circuit+for+antenna+receiver+(short+waves)&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&w&biw=1179&bih=880#imgrc=H1Qu2RB6qDqIzM

Comment: Here's the MIT course that can help you :) https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-013-electromagnetics-and-applications-spring-2009/  - with all sources of applications and all the stuff that you need to know to answer questions like the one you asked here

Comment: @MihaiB., Thanks, if you care to post a brief answer, I'll be glad to accept it.